# Set Checkbox as Checked by using id attribute as parameter

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, checked, prop

I want to make a checkbox as "checked" by using its "id" attribute as the parameter via jQuery. In fact, if I specifically assign the checkbox with its id (checkbox1) directly, this works :

```
$("input:checkbox[id=checkbox1]").prop('checked', true);
```

But, I want to have the id as the parameter. So, here's what I tried (and didn't work):

```
var param="checkbox1";
$("input:checkbox[id="+param+"]").prop('checked', true);
```

I guess I may be doing something wrong with quotations. Still couldn't figure it out though by trying many combinations. How do you think I should approach?

Comment: On a side note if you are using id you could just do `$("#"+param).prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Your JS works here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqKWa/

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Yet, I still cannot make it work though... Strange, I even tried attr instead of prop. I think I should check some more serious problems.